# How can I get the label scores for spacy NER model?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I have trained spacy blank model and trying to get the scores/confidence score of the labels the model attached to the entities.

```
nlp = spacy.load('output_/model-best')
doc = nlp("hello world")
for entity in doc.ents:
    print(entity.text, entity.label_)
```

But how to get the score of the label?

Comment: What component are you trying to get the score for? If you're using NER it doesn't have confidence scores.

Comment: @polm23 understood, I have already figured out that NER and spancat won't work when I have a specific mapping of functions and their variables names + for each variable all it's possible values list. 
So for example if function ```foo``` has 2 variables ```bo``` and ```du``` then I will label each of the possible values (including appended by user input) with ```foo.bo``` and ```foo.du```. For example: ```[text: "kuku", annotations: [(0,4,"foo.bo"]}``` and so on....